# nightwatch.js: keyboard action

Tags: javascript, keyboard, interaction, nightwatch.js

I am using `nightwatch.js` to write automation scripts. I want to use keyboard keys but it seems not working.

**I have tried:**

```
hitEnter: function () {
        this.setValue('@submitButton', this.Keys.ENTER);
    }
```

call this function in `test_file.js` as

```
loginPage
     .hitEnter();
```

It gives error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ENTER' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Keys.ENTER
```

In this case, this = loginPage , not browser, you should execute with browser object through api :

```
this.setValue('@submitButton', this.api.Keys.ENTER);
```

edit:
api will return an object which contains " custom command/assertion" + "core command/assertion" + "global variables". Keys is core command ,based on selenium.

Comment: what is `api` in `this.api.Keys.ENTER`?

Comment: It will return an object which contains " custom command/assertion" +  "core command/assertion" +  "global variables".  Keys is core command ,based on selenium.